# iBatis, queryWithRowHandler ResultSet already closed

Tags: jakarta-ee, oracle11g, weblogic, ibatis

We have an issue which occurs only on production environment.

RowHandler should be executed for about 63 rows, but it fails processing from 1 to 3 rows.

There is no connection/cursor closing in our RowHandler.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Result set already closed
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet.checkResultSet(ResultSet.java:144)
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet.preInvocationHandler(ResultSet.java:97)
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet_oracle_jdbc_driver_OracleResultSetImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.execution.SqlExecutor.handleResults(SqlExecutor.java:383)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.execution.SqlExecutor.handleMultipleResults(SqlExecutor.java:300)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.execution.SqlExecutor.executeQuery(SqlExecutor.java:189)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.sqlExecuteQuery(MappedStatement.java:222)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryWithCallback(MappedStatement.java:191)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryWithRowHandler(MappedStatement.java:149)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryWithRowHandler(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:601)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryWithRowHandler(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:157)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientImpl.queryWithRowHandler(SqlMapClientImpl.java:133)
```

My RowHandler looks like:

```
public class CustomerRowHandler extends AbstractRowHandler {
    private UserContextTiny userCtx;
    private MarketingActionData mrkData;
    private TaskManager taskManager;
    private Logger logger = new Logger(getClass());

    public CustomerRowHandler(UserContextTiny userCtx, TaskData task, MarketingActionData mrkData) {
        this.userCtx = userCtx;
        this.mrkData = mrkData;
        this.taskManager = new TaskManager(task.getId());
    }

    public void handleRow(Object valueObject) {
        String methodName = "handleRow";
        MarketingPersonalData recipient = (MarketingPersonalData)valueObject;
        try {
            MarketingActionDataSource ds = new MarketingActionDataSource();
            Account account = recipient.getAccount();
            Customer customer = recipient.getCustomer();
            if (account != null) {
                Long tierId = AccountDAO.getInstance().getAccountTier(account.getAccId(), DateTimeProvider.getInstance().getCurrentDate());
                DictionaryObject tier = (DictionaryObject) CLMCacheHolder.getGlobal().getRegion(EJBCacheRegions.TIERS).getElement(tierId);
                account.setAccTierCode(tier.getCode());
                account.setAccTierName(tier.getName().getValue(customer.getCusLngCode()));
                account.setTierId(tierId);
            }
            ds.setAccountData(account);
            ds.setCustomerData(customer);
            ds.setProspectData(recipient.getProspect());

            GeneratedMessageData genMsg = MessageProcessor.generateMessage(NotificationTemplateData.Type.MARKETING_ACTION, recipient.getCustomer().getCusLngCode(), mrkData.getChnCode(), mrkData.getNtmId(), ds);
            SendNotificationData sendDto = new SendNotificationData(genMsg);
            sendDto.setMrkId(mrkData.getId());
            sendDto.setToCusId(recipient.getCustomer().getCusId());
            sendDto.setAdvId(mrkData.getAdvId());
            sendDto.setType(CommunicationData.Type.MARKETING_ACTION);
            sendDto.setExternalId(CommunicationDAO.generateExternalId(sendDto.getType(), mrkData.getId(), mrkData.getCreateDate()));
            if (mrkData.getExpirationDate() != null) {
                sendDto.setExpirationDate(new Timestamp(mrkData.getExpirationDate().getTime()));
            }
            if (mrkData.getSendAfterDate() != null) {
                sendDto.setSentAfter(new Timestamp(mrkData.getSendAfterDate().getTime()));
            }
            if (NotificationTemplateData.Handler.SOAP.equals(genMsg.getNtmHandler()) || NotificationTemplateData.Handler.SYNC.equals(genMsg.getNtmHandler()) || Channels.SMS.equals(mrkData.getChnCode())) {
                sendDto.setStatus(CommunicationData.Status.PENDING);
            }
            sendDto.setChannel(mrkData.getChnCode());
            // attach coupons generated in this communication
            sendDto.setCoupons(new ArrayList<Long>());
            if (ds.isCouponDataAvailable()) {
                for (CouponData coupon : ds.getCoupons()) {
                    sendDto.getCoupons().add(coupon.getId());
                }
            }

            // send notification
            notificationManager.sendNotification(userCtx, sendDto, mrkData.isPermissionIgnore(), false, false);
            sendCount++;

        } catch (ApplicationException e) {
            rejectCount++;
            logger.info(methodName, "Mailing not sent due to: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            taskManager.taskLog("Mailing not sent to customer \"" + recipient.getCustomer().getCusFirstName() + " " + recipient.getCustomer().getCusLastName() + "\" (id: " + recipient.getCustomer().getCusId() + ") due to: " + e.getMessage(), INFO);
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            rejectCount++;
            logger.info(methodName, "Mailing not sent due to: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            taskManager.taskLog("Mailing not sent to customer \"" + recipient.getCustomer().getCusFirstName() + " " + recipient.getCustomer().getCusLastName() + "\" (id: " + recipient.getCustomer().getCusId() + ") due to: " + e.getMessage(), INFO);
            throw e;            
        } 
    }
}
```

And it is used by:

```
public void selectMarketingPersonalData(UserContextTiny userCtx, Long mrkId, RowHandler rh) {
    getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryWithRowHandler("MARKETING_ACTION.selectMarketingPersonalData", mrkId, rh);
}
```

Query which is executed:

```
<select id="selectMarketingPersonalData" parameterClass="java.lang.Long" resultMap="MarketingPersonalDataResultMap">
    SELECT ACC_FIRST_ISS_DATE, ACC_FIRST_RED_DATE, ACC_ID, ACC_ISS_POINTS, ACC_LAST_ISS_DATE, ACC_LAST_RED_DATE,
        ACC_NO, ACC_NUM_OF_CARDS, ACC_POINTS_BALANCE, ACC_RED_POINTS, ACC_REGISTER_DATE, ACC_STATUS, ACC_TRN_COUNT,
        CUS_BIRTH_DATE, PKG_ACCOUNTS.GetCusDynamicEarn(CUS_ID) CUS_DYNAMIC_EARN, CUS_FIRST_NAME, CUS_ID, CUS_LAST_NAME, CUS_LNG_CODE, CUS_PARTICIPANT_ID, CUS_TITLE,
        CUS_PERMISSION_EMAIL, CUS_PERMISSION_SMS, CUS_PERMISSION_POST, CUS_PERMISSION_PHONE, CUS_SALUTATION, CUS_DOCUMENT_ID, CUS_DOCUMENT_TYPE,
        CUS_CIF_NUMBER, CUS_CST_ID, CUS_BRANCH_NUMBER, CUS_DEPENDENT_NBR, CUS_GENDER, CUS_MARITAL_STATUS, CUS_OPEN_DATE,
        CUS_PREF_COM_CHANNEL, CUS_SECOND_NAME, CUS_SEGMENT, CUS_SUB_SEGMENT, CUS_BANK_OFFICER,
        ADR_ID, ADR_TYPE, ADR_COUNTRY, ADR_STATE, ADR_CITY, ADR_ZIP_CODE, ADR_STREET_NAME, ADR_STREET_NAME_2, ADR_HOUSE_NO, ADR_HOME_PHONE, 
        ADR_MOBILE, ADR_EMAIL, ADR_ADDITIONAL_INFO, ADR_POSTAL_BOUNCED_FLAG, ADR_EMAIL_BOUNCED_FLAG, ADR_SCORING, 
        ADR_SCORING_DATE, ADR_STREET_PREFIX, ADR_FAX, ADR_SECOND_EMAIL, ADR_SECOND_PHONE, ADR_ALTERNATE_PHONE,
        ADR_BUSINESS_PHONE, ADR_CITIZENSHIP_CODE,ADR_ADDRESS_1,ADR_ADDRESS_2,ADR_ADDRESS_3,ADR_ADDRESS_4,
        ADR_MOBILE_BOUNCED_FLAG, ADR_POSTAL_BOUNCED_REASON, ADR_POSTAL_DATE, ADR_MOBILE_DATE, ADR_EMAIL_DATE,
        PPS_ID, PPS_FIRST_NAME, PPS_LAST_NAME, PPS_EMAIL, PPS_DATA_USAGE_FLAG, PPS_PERMISSION_POSTAL,
        PPS_SOURCE, PPS_DATE, PPS_TEXT_1, PPS_TEXT_2, PPS_TEXT_3, PPS_TEXT_4, PPS_TEXT_5, PPS_DATE_1, PPS_DATE_2,
        PPS_DATE_3, PPS_DATE_4, PPS_DATE_5, PPS_NUMERIC_1, PPS_NUMERIC_2, PPS_NUMERIC_3, PPS_NUMERIC_4, PPS_NUMERIC_5,
        PPS_SALUTATION
    FROM LCT_MARKETING_ACTION_TMP
        LEFT OUTER JOIN LCT_ACCOUNTS ON MAT_ACC_ID = ACC_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN LCT_CUSTOMERS ON MAT_CUS_ID = CUS_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN LCT_PROSPECTS ON MAT_PPS_ID = PPS_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN LCT_ADDRESSES ON MAT_ADR_ID = ADR_ID
    WHERE MAT_MRK_ID = #value#
</select>
```

What could be the reason of this issue? We cannot reproduce it on test environments.

Answer (score -1):

There are many situations where resultset is automatically closed like when the Statement object that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

For more info check the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

It will be better if you can give the code instead of stacktrace in the question.

Comment: I had to check if I can add code to this ticket. Already done.